# javascript & jquery selection and get value and attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors

kindly help me to select and get the value of my option and the attribute of its.

here my sample code with:

html----

```
<div class="cart">
    <select class="a">
        <option value="1" prodID="12354">1</option>
        <option value="2" prodID="11364">2</option>
        <option value="3" prodID="16352">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jq srcipt----

```
$(".cart").on('change load', '.a select', function(){
    alert(//the value);
    alert(//the value of attribure prodID);
})
```

expected to be pop out:

```
if 1 is selected
    alert 1(value) and 12354(attr)

if 3 is selected alert 3 and 16352
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct your selector to `select.a` . .`a select` means an element with class `a` and child `select`
2. You only need the change event.
3. Use the `:selected` selector to get the current selected option and `attr()` to get the `prodID` attribute

```js
$(".cart").on('change', 'select.a', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  console.log($(':selected').attr('data-prod-id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart">
  <select class="a">
    <option value="1" data-prod-id="12354">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-prod-id="11364">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-prod-id="16352">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @mon-sun, I dont understand. Do you mean do I have a suggested name for the attribute?

Comment: @mon-sun, use `data-prod-id`. It is good practice to prefix with `data-` because it ensures that attribute will not become a standard attribute in future browsers and HTML specs

Comment: and how can i call it in right way?
alert($(this).find(':selected').attr('data-prod-id'));

Answer (score 5):

You need to use change event only:

```
$(".cart select").on('change', function(){
  alert(this.value);
  alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('prodID'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/90L0uLz4/)**

`prodID` is not a valid attribute. However i would suggest you to use custom attribute as `data-prodID`.

```
 <select class="a">
  <option value="1" data-prodID="12354">1</option>
  <option value="2" data-prodID="11364">2</option>
  <option value="3" data-prodID="16352">3</option>
 </select>
```

and then get the custom option value using:

```
 $(this).find('option:selected').data('prodID');
```

Comment: its returns undefined using data-prodID. but its fine with invalid attribure